# ScopeConfigInterface as parameter in constructor - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm working with `Magento 2`, I'm still new.
I have this constructor inside a controller class:

```
public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
      $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
      return parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

It was working until I added the ScopeConfigInterface. 
Now, when I load my page I get this error:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to xxx\Customer\Controller\Login::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface, none given, called in...
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted folder:

`"var/generation"`

And that solved the problem.